# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'scroller'

Tags: javascript, android, eclipse

While my webpage loads in the webview I get this error in the logcat:

> E/Web Console(553): Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no
>   method 'scroller' at https://xxx.xxxxx.com/assets/js/m/common.js:2

I am getting this error even after including the **@JavascriptInterface** annotation like this:

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
    class JsObject 
    {  
      @JavascriptInterface  
      public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }  
    }  
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
```

Is there any other way to solve this problem ? Please help.